# How do I chain async methods inside React useEffect() hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise, react-context

I am building an e-commerce site with ReactJS and Commerce.js. I have a checkout context provider which is responsible for storing all state and functionality related to the checkout and order data. Below is the basic shape of the checkout state being stored in the context:

```
const initialState = {
  checkout_token: {
    id: "123456789"
  },
  order_data: {
    fulfillment: {
      shipping_options: [],
      shipping_countries: {},
      shipping_subdivisions: {},
      shipping_option: "",
    },
  }
}
```

I need to update the fulfillment section of my checkout data. This requires an API request to commerce.js using the `checkout_token.id` chained with a method call that updates the relevant part of checkout state. Here is one of the 3 methods I use to do this. You can assume the dispatch method works:

```
const setShippingCountries = (tokenId) => {
    commerce.services
      .localeListShippingCountries(tokenId)
      .then((countries) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.SET_SHIPPING_COUNTRIES,
          countries,
        });
      })
  };
```

Anytime that the checkout token is changed, I need to update the fulfillment data. I tried doing this with the following `useEffect()` hook. Note that `isMounted` is a ref used to stop the effect on mount:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current && Object.keys(state.checkout_token).length > 0) {
      setShippingCountries(state.checkout_token.id);
      setSubdivisions(state.order_data.fulfillment.shipping_countries[0]);
      setShippingOptions(state...shipping_countries[0], 
        state...shipping_subdivisions[0]); //Forgive my abbreviation :)
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true; 
    }
  }, [state.checkout_token.id]);
```

Here is my error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')`

This is caused because each method references data that was set in the line before. But the data is not updated when I reach the next line. I have tried turning them into `Promises` and chaining them but I was unable to get it right. I also tried using `async...await` but couldn't figure that out either. What is the best way to change these methods so that they are called synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async await version would look like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const f = async () => {
            await setShippingCountries(state.checkout_token.id);
            await setSubdivisions(state.order_data.fulfillment.shipping_countries[0]);
            await setShippingOptions(state.shipping_countries[0]);
        }
        if (isMounted.current && Object.keys(state.checkout_token).length > 0) {
            f()
        } else {
            isMounted.current = true;
        }
    }, [state.checkout_token.id]);
```

Comment: thanks for the response! When I use this, it says that "await has no effect on this type of expression." and I still get an error. Is that because the 3 functions themselves are not asynchronous?

Comment: Indeed, they need to return a promise.
Note that set states are asynchronous by design, so what you are trying to do goes against the react way.
What you should do instead is only set the state once, and get the needed values from the previous functions synchronously
const a = await f1();
const b = await f2(a);
const c = await f3(b);
setState(c);

Comment: Ok that helps. I ended up using 3 separate useEffect() hooks where each hook depends on the state of the variable in the previous hook. So once the countries are set, the subdivision api call is triggered, etc. Though your answer isn't exactly how I implemented it, it led me to a working solution. Thanks for the help!